# A limit question trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Is there a solution to this question? I can't solve it.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n}$$

Comment: What is the behavior of this function for fixed $x$ and large $n$ ?

Comment: left and right.And range of x : [0,1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n>0$ an integer number. Notice that for any real number $x$ we have $$-\frac1n\le\frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n}\le\frac1n$$
Then, from the Squeeze Theorem follows
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin(n^2x)}{n}=0$$

Comment: hmm. i get it. so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we have $|\sin(x)|\le 1$